# Keep accordion tab open after refreshed (bootstrap code)

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-accordion

How do I keep my active tab open after I refresh my web. I used bootstrap (w3school) codes for these;

```
<script>
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.maxHeight){
            panel.style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
            panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

html

```
<button class="accordion"><div class="panel-heading">Application Usages</div></button>
```

Thank you

Comment: You may want to do more research before posting, there are a lot topics about this with answers already.

If you have something more specific than the others, revise your question to highlight it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keep JQuery accordion open after refresh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26337871/keep-jquery-accordion-open-after-refresh)